# Mixing symbols and numerical reference marks

Tags: quotations, citation

In the case of a block quotation from a secondary source that is required to feature any original citations appearing in that material, would the convention of employing a numerical citation reference mark preceding the block (at the end the signal phrase) to cite the block's origin while retaining all original citations within that secondary source, but distinguishing them, via symbols be a readily grasped approach?

It's surprising that there seems to be very little, in terms of reference works, addressing this. There are most certainly times where a block quotation must incorporate pre-existing citations and where some distinction between the surrounding notes in the main text and the historical notes in the excerpt are called for. Note that this refers to a case where in-line citations are not part of the house style.

Comment: It's common to mix symbolic and numeric when you want to include both the author's original notes and later editorial marks, especially in later editions of texts that require further annotation from editor or translator. It's also possible to mix numeric with letters in Latin or Greek alphabets. I don't have any example at the moment, but I'm sure if you have an edition of Kant or some other German philosopher somewhere, you'll find examples.

Comment: Thank you. A style guide's – any style guide's – guidance on mixing symbolic and numeric reference marks is unknown to me, but it is exactly that which I seek (and still hope to be referred to), yet absent that, such existing works as those mentioned in philosophy to use as a reference must fill in.